# Difference between 'at' and 'in'

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

Is **at** used for a small town while **in** is used for a big city/country? Take the following examples:

> I'm at home
>
> I'm at Houston.
>
> I'm in Texas
>
> I'm in Ghana

Comment: Also, Houston is the fourth largest city in the country, so it would not be a good example of using "at" with a small town.

Comment: @Tashus, Houston, Missouri is only about 2,000 people. Maybe that's the one they meant.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would say "in" a place or building. So "in Houston," which is in fact a large city rather than a small town. Size is irrelevant: you can idiomatically say, "I am in my apartment."

"Home" is an exception, perhaps because the word has connotations that extend beyond mere designation of places or buildings. Nor is the word limited to physical space. It may refer to situations. "I'm at home giving television interviews" means "I am comfortable giving television interviews."